# Re-using a vector while not sacrificing elegance

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following class definition (abridged):

```
class A {
public:
    DigraphNode getBestMove(DigraphNode node) {
        nn.clear(); 
        getOutNeighbors(node, nn); // fills nn
        ...
    }
private:
    vector<DigraphNode> nn;
    Heuristic *heuristic;    
}
```

In the original non-optimized version, nn used to be declared inside the getBestMove method and the method itself was declared as const. However, re-allocations of nn took a lot of the execution time. So, I decided to share nn between the invocations of getBestMove by making it a class member. This resulted in time speed-up, but at the cost of reduced readability:

-- I cannot make the method const anymore, since it modifies nn.

-- Having an extra class member just to enable reuse does not feel right.

-- Instead of returning a vector (which required allocating a vector to accumulate the result), getOutNeighbors() now takes a vector reference as a parameter.

Is there a better alternative for the kind of reuse I am trying to achieve?

EDIT: To clarify, DigraphNode is the synonym I defined for Digraph::Node of the Lemon graph library. I am of the impression that this is a small type and that passing nodes by value is perfectly fine.

Comment: What would you consider _having elegance_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `vector<DigraphNode> nn;`

Comment: Why are you passing `DiagraphNode` by value? What is `DiagraphNode`?

Comment: If you down-vote the question, please at least leave a comment explaining what is wrong with the question in your opinion. This will give me a chance to improve.

Comment: static variable inside of the function might work, also pimpl hides implementation if don't like to change header files often.

Comment: `Instead of returning a vector (which required allocating a vector to accumulate the result), ` If your compiler supports (N)RVO optimizations, and you've implemented the function where (N)RVO can be used, returning a vector shouldn't have caused such a degradation in speed.

Comment: mlt, thanks for the great suggestion (about using static)! The Pimpl idiom, at least as described at http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom, looks complicated.

Comment: `mutable` counters the effects of `const`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The cost is likely not due to returning of a vector, but due to allocating the vector's internal storage over and over.

Comment: Exactly. Does RVO help with this? I experimented both ways and using a reference parameter was significantly faster than returning the vector into the static variable.

Comment: Interestingly, when I profiled with valgrind, it attributed the cost to push_back, while allocating the vector did not appear at all...

Answer (score 0):

Q. -- I cannot make the method const anymore, since it modifies nn.

A. you can declare nn as `mutable` then the function still can be const.

```
mutable vector<DigraphNode> nn;
```

Q. -- Having an extra class member just to enable reuse does not feel right.

A. It is not just not pretty, it is also not safe, especially if you work multi-threaded. It seem the `nn` should be declared as local variable at the caller, and be given as a parameter to the function.
something like this:

```
DigraphNode getBestMove(const DigraphNode& node, vector<DigraphNode>& nn)const{
  if (nn.empty()){
    //in case you don't want to fill it outside you can do it here.
    getOutNeighbors(node, nn); // fills nn
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In my case, nn is a temporary variable used by getBestMove. It does not have any meaning to the caller.

Comment: I understood it, but even if it is mean less, if you want to share it between sessions, it better be declared outside the class. you can hide it in some `typedef` and call it search handler...

Comment: Why is this better than declaring it static in getBestMove?

Comment: If you declare it static: 1. it is not thread safe. 2. it is hard to reset(like if you begin a new search).